# For any $a \in \Bbb{Z}$, can we always find two prime numbers $p, q$, such that $p - q \in (a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, goldbachs-conjecture

This is a major weakening of many prime sum / difference existence questions.

Let $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $(a)$ the ideal generated by $a$.  Then do there exist two primes $p, q$ such that $p - q \in (a)$ at least?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  Pick a prime $q$ not dividing $a$.  Then Dirichlet tells us there are infinitely many primes $p\equiv q \pmod a$.

Comment: @lulu It seems you forgot the simple answers the last time around (in the dupe), so here is a comment to remind you.

Comment: @BillDubuque  Thanks!  Definitely missed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done in an elementary way; Dirichlet is extreme overkill.

To see this, note that there are infinitely many primes, but only finitely many remainders on division by $a$.  By the pigeonhole principle, there are two primes $p$ and $q$ with the same remainder, and we are done.

Comment: But it's still Dirichlet! (box principle).